# Как получить ответ от SMTP сервера в phpMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, response

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться, как получить ответ сервера при отправке письма через phpMailer? Везде в примерах написан такой формат, типа если $mail->send(), то «success»… а вот иначе $mail->errorInfo()… а вот можно как-то получить ответ от сервера при успешном send()? В частности сейчас использую почтовый сервис который шлет ответ со статусами (написано в документации какие могут быть ответы), ведь можно выполнить успешный send(), а получить например недоставку письма по причине переполнения почты получателя, или несуществования email на который отправляем… Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Comment: **при успешном** send() вы про недоставку письма по причине переполнения почты получателя, или несуществования email на который отправляем **не узнаете.** Это взаимоисключающие понятия. Если сенд успешный, то либо письмо доставлено локальному получателю **без ошибок,** либо поставлено в очередь на отправку на другой сервер. И в этом случае о проблемах  с доставкой вы узнаете уже только из почтового ящика

Comment: Но вот я нагуглил за вас, $mail->getSMTPInstance()->getError(); если прям так надо

Comment: @Ипатьев Спасибо за ответ. Я тоже документацию нашел на метод send() он возвращает булево, true/false... Но хотя бы статус сервера можно как то получить, должен быть 250 вроде (в документации вроде так написано, если всё успешно вернем статус 250 или подобное)